# Exam Class + \xcolor + \tikz conflict: incompatible color def

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, exam

Code is kicking out this warning:

`Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 97.`

Colors are being used in 3 ways in this maths worksheet:

1. draw yellow highlighted box to enclose the final answer

Ex: `\colorbox{yellow}{$x=\dfrac{\log{34}}`

2. apply color to certain exponents and log bases

Ex: `$\textcolor{red}{\cancel{log_4}}(5x+15)=\textcolor{red}{\cancel{log_4}}(35)$`

3. using tikz, draw blue arrow to indicate transition to next step of solution procedure.

Ex: `$5^{x-3}=35 \tikz[baseline=-0.65ex]\draw[arr] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0); \log 5^{x-3} = \log 35$` (h/t @zarko)

After searching several tex.stack posts, I tried inserting `usepackage{xcolor}` immediately before `\usepackage{tikz}`. This edit failed to remove warning message.

Your assistance in resolving this issue is deeply appreciated!

FYI: **Using exam class because it provides  `printanswers` and `%printanswers`** (i.e. don't print answers) commands.

mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{arr/.style = {blue,-{Triangle[angle=60:1pt 3]}, thick,
                       shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm}
          } 
\pagestyle{head}
\header{\textbf{ Algebra II: TEST 4 REVIEW (Unit 14: Logarithms)}}
{}
{} 
\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
 }
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added
\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries, 
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother
\newlength{\SolutionSpace}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}
{\setlength{\SolutionSpace}{5cm}
    \colorsolutionboxes 
\definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{0.8}}% solutions are printed
{\setlength{\SolutionSpace}{0cm}
    \colorsolutionboxes 
    \definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{1}}% solutions are not being printed
%*********************************************
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Solve for $x$. If necessary, round answers to 2 decimal places.}}
%%% Prob #1
\task 
$2 \bm{\cdot}5^{x-3}-7=61$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
$2 \bm{\cdot}5^{x-3}=68$\bigskip
$\dfrac{\cancel{2}\bm{\cdot}5^{x-3}}{\cancel{2}} =\dfrac{68}{2}$\bigskip
$5^{x-3}=35 \tikz[baseline=-0.65ex]\draw[arr] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0);
\log 5^{x-3} = \log 35$\bigskip
$(x-3)\log5=\log{34}$\bigskip
$\dfrac{(x-3)\cancel{\log5}}{\cancel{\log5}}=\dfrac{\log{34}}{\log5}$\bigskip
$x-3=\dfrac{\log{34}}{\log5}$\hphantom{(}\hphantom{(}\hphantom{(}
\colorbox{yellow}{$x=\dfrac{\log{34}}{\log5}+3\approx5.19$}
\end{solutionorbox}

%%% Prob #2
\task 
$\log_4(x+3)+\log_45=\log_4{35}$
\vspace{.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
$\log_4(x+3)(5)=\log_4(35)$\bigskip
$\textcolor{red}{\cancel{log_4}}(5x+15)=\textcolor{red}{\cancel{log_4}}(35)$\bigskip
$5x+15=35$\bigskip
$5x=20$\hphantom{(}\hphantom{(}\hphantom{(}
\colorbox{yellow}{$x=4$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%%% Prob #3
\task 
$\log_4(3x+4)=3$\vspace{.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
Hint: If $\log_{\textcolor{red}{a}}N=\textcolor{blue}{x}$, then $\textcolor{red}{a}^{\textcolor{blue}{x}}=N$.\bigskip
$4^3=3x+4 \tikz[baseline=-0.65ex]\draw[arr] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0);64=3x+4$\bigskip
$3x=60$\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$x=20$}
\end{solutionorbox}

\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should shorten your example, most of it is certainly not needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I hear your admonition. But I've only included 2 of 30 math problems to show the 3 uses of color involving 3 packages. What  specifically should I cut from the OP? I will make any changes you suggest. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I don't care what you cut, but 90 lines, various packages and lots of details are too much. Remove as much as you can while retaining the warning.

Comment: An MWE would be `\documentclass{exam} \usepackage{xcolor} \printanswers \colorsolutionboxes \begin{document} \begin{solutionorbox} \end{solutionorbox} \end{document}`. So, it seems that the `exam` class uses a color definition that is compatible with the `color` package and hence the `xcolor` package complains.

Comment: But I don't really understand what is wrong here, because the color definition the package uses is `\definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{0.8}` and this should be fine with `xcolor` as well.

Comment: @JasperHabicht the colorfbox command is faulty. Try `\renewcommand{\colorfbox}[2]{\colorlet{saved@color}{.}{\color{#1}\fbox{\color{saved@color}#2}}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I already found out by myself in this very moment =) Thank you!

Comment: @JasperHabicht and Ulrike Fishcer....Thanks to both of you for the fix. Is it possible to briefly explain why this code string resolves the conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (very) minimal working example would be:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\printanswers 
\colorsolutionboxes 
\definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{0.8}

\begin{document} 
\begin{solutionorbox} 
Foo
\end{solutionorbox} 
\end{document}
```

What you get is a warning that does not really do any harm. The reason you get this warning is that the `exam` package uses a command syntax that is specific to the `color` package. The `xcolor` package understands this syntax as well, but it favours a different, newer syntax.

You can solve this by adding a few lines to your preamble:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\renewcommand{\colorfbox}[2]{%
  \colorlet{currentColor}{.}%
  {\color{#1}\fbox{\color{currentColor}#2}}%
}

\printanswers 
\colorsolutionboxes 
\definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{0.8}

\begin{document} 
\begin{solutionorbox} 
Foo
\end{solutionorbox} 
\end{document}
```

(Thanks to Ulrike Fischer for confirming this!)

---

What is the reason for this? The culprit is this definition in the file `exam.cls` (stripped off the comments):

```
\newcommand{\colorfbox}[2]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname\string\color@saved@color\endcsname\current@color%
  {\color{#1}\fbox{\color{saved@color}#2}}%
}
```

It is meant to create a box around something and to draw the frame of the box in a certain color while keeping the contents of the box in the color that has been used outside of the box. The defintion makes use of a syntax that works well if the `color` package is loaded.

Using the `xcolor` package, the current color can be more easily accessed via the color name `.`. So, the above could be rewritten as:

```
\newcommand{\colorfbox}[2]{%
  \colorlet{currentColor}{.}%
  {\color{#1}\fbox{\color{currentColor}#2}}%
}
```

A warning about an "incompatible color definition" is issued when the `xcolor` package is loaded and TeX stumbles over some color definition that is stored in a command that starts with `\color@`. The original defintion of `\colorfbox` defines such a command and hence the warning is issued every time this command is used. The rewritten code solves this problem.

Comment: Thank you for being a patient and very helpful tex teacher. Your explanation will be put to good use the next time I encounter this problem. The world is a better place with generous people like you and Ulrike.

Comment: In your comments you suggest this code revision: ```\newcommand{\colorfbox}[2]{% \colorlet{currentColor}{.}% {\color{#1}\fbox{\color{currentColor}#2}}% }``` But I didn't see these code lines in your rewrite above. So is it okay to replace ```\renewcommand{\colorfbox}[2]{%
  \colorlet{currentColor}{.}%
  {\color{#1}\fbox{\color{currentColor}#2}}%
}``` with the aforementioned code which you suggest is more direct current color? BTW, what does ```current color``` mean? Thanks!

Comment: @SiuslawMath You need to use `\renewcommand` to overwrite some defintion. This is why I used this in my MWE, because here, we *overwrite* the definition of the package. I used `\newcommand` in the comments, because you would use this if you *replaced* the relevant part of the code in the package directly. The rest of the two code snippets is exactly the same.

Comment: @SiuslawMath With "current color" I mean the color that is currently used, that is, the color the text has before the box is drawn. This color can be accessed using `.`, but this color changes as soon as the box is drawn with a colored frame. Therefore, we need to store this color somewhere, and I just used the name `currentColor` to this end. It could also be another name, it doesn't matter. After the box has been drawn, I use `\color{currentColor}` to restore the current color to the color that was the current color before the box was drawn.